# How to match the width of the dropdown container to the width of the parent (Dropdown)

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 0vh 0vh 1vh 1vh;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a onclick="show2()" class="nav-link active-link dropbtn" href="#"><span>Dropdown</span></a>
  <ul id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a class="a" href="#">Content</a></li>
    <li><a class="a" href="#">Content</a></li>
    <li><a class="a" href="#">Content</a></li>
    <li><a class="a" href="#">Content</a></li>
    <li><a class="a" href="#">Content</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How can the width of Dropdown list container match the width of the parent container that's on the navbar

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I exactly understand your question but you could try using css to set the width or height to 100% which should match the height and width of the div your html is embedded inside of.
The css:

```
 width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```